# Manage files with no checked in version - CAML query

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, client-object-model

I am using Office 365. We have a document library containing more than 12000+ documents, with  a number of folders and subfolders.

I need to find a way to get all document which have no checked in version.

I tried to use "Manage files with no checked in version" in library settings, but no luck since its already reached the maximum threshold.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in client side scripting...i wasted my hours before quitting..